# Angular 16 build mismatch

Tags: angular, build, configuration, environment, production

According to the docs `ng build` builds artifacts for production. My environment is as follows: *environment.development.ts* for development and *environment.ts* for production. When I build the app it uses the development environment instead of production. Also I tried `ng build --configuration=production` but the output is the same.

Content of *angular.json*

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "cli": {
    "packageManager": "npm"
  },
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/m",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am missing?

Comment: Check what you have in your `angular.json` (you can share it with us)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I've updated the question with the content of angular.json

Comment: Looks normal to me, are you sure you are  only importing from `src/environments/environment.ts` in your code base ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Yes. Due to the addition of fileReplacements in Angular 16 am sure no import is required in app.component.ts

Comment: `fileReplacements` is not new and was existing long before.

Comment: Then I think most YouTubers and bloggers who are talking about what's new in Angular 16 are misleading people. Do I need to add this:  ``import { environment } from './../environments/environment';`` in app.compoent.ts?

Comment: Depends what do you need them for.

Comment: @KennedyMwenda yes, import everything from just. `environment`. for development there is a replacement that will swap `environment.development` in place of just `environment` file and the different one will be used

Comment: @Andrei Thanks. I realized I was importing ``environment.development`` in services instead of ``environment``

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was importing `environment.development` instead of `environment` in services.